# Not able to generate coverage

Tags: go, assert

I have something like below in my test file

```
package stringutil

import (
    "testing"
    "gotest.tools/assert"
)
```

When I try to test it I get error

```
$ go test github.com/user/stringutil
# github.com/user/stringutil
package github.com/user/stringutil (test)
        imports gotest.tools/assert
        imports gotest.tools/v3/assert/cmp: code in directory C:\Users\abc\go\src\gotest.tools\assert\cmp expects import "gotest.tools/assert/cmp"
FAIL    github.com/user/stringutil [setup failed]
FAIL
```

then I added "gotest.tools/assert/cmp" in import.

```
package stringutil

import (
    "testing"
    "gotest.tools/assert"
    "gotest.tools/assert/cmp"
)
```

When I tried testing it I got next error

```
$ go test github.com/user/stringutil
# github.com/user/stringutil
package github.com/user/stringutil (test)
        imports gotest.tools/assert
        imports gotest.tools/v3/internal/format: code in directory C:\Users\abc\go\src\gotest.tools\internal\format expects import "gotest.tools/internal/format"
FAIL    github.com/user/stringutil [setup failed]
FAIL
```

Then I added "gotest.tools/internal/format" in import

```
package stringutil

import (
    "testing"
    "gotest.tools/assert"
    "gotest.tools/assert/cmp"
    "gotest.tools/internal/format"
)
```

Now I got another error while testing it

```
$ go test github.com/user/stringutil
# github.com/user/stringutil
package github.com/user/stringutil (test)
        imports gotest.tools/assert
        imports gotest.tools/v3/assert/cmp
        imports gotest.tools/v3/internal/format
        imports gotest.tools/v3/internal/difflib: code in directory C:\Users\abc\go\src\gotest.tools\internal\difflib expects import "gotest.tools/internal/difflib"
FAIL    github.com/user/stringutil [setup failed]
FAIL
```

then I added "gotest.tools/internal/difflib" in import

```
package stringutil

import (
    "testing"
    "gotest.tools/assert"
    "gotest.tools/assert/cmp"
    "gotest.tools/internal/format"
    "gotest.tools/internal/difflib"
)
```

Now I got different error

```
$ go test github.com/user/stringutil
# github.com/user/stringutil
package github.com/user/stringutil (test)
        imports gotest.tools/internal/difflib: use of internal package gotest.tools/internal/difflib not allowed
FAIL    github.com/user/stringutil [setup failed]
FAIL
```

If I do not use assert My test works

```
$ go test github.com/user/stringutil
ok      github.com/user/stringutil      0.435s
```

Looks like there is a issue with assert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the usage instructions](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotest.tools):

> With Go modules enabled (go1.11+)
>
> get gotest.tools/v3
>
> import "gotest.tools/v3/assert"

So instead of importing `gotest.tools/assert` you need to import `gotest.tools/v3/assert`. This will bring in the latest version of the package (I am assuming you are using modules; this is the default with the latest version of go unless you are working in GOPATH and dont have a go.mod).

Importing `gotest.tools/assert` will bring in an old non module aware version. This is discussed in some detail in [an issue](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotest.tools/issues/166) which includes the comment

> gotest.tools/assert is only a valid import for the v3 version of the package, which is long out of date

As your comments indicate that you are not using modules I have had another look. It appears that the comment in the above issue is incorrect and the master of this project now includes support for modules. Unfortunately this has broken its use with projects that do not support modules. You could get an older release (would need to use git) or use modules in your project (the approach I recommend).

To get the older release change to the gotest.tools folder (`C:\Users\abc\go\src\gotest.tools` in your case) and run `git checkout v2.3.0` (2.3.0 probably works but you may need to go back to 2.2.0). Note that this means you will be using an older version of the package.

Comment: $ go get gotest.tools/v3
package gotest.tools/v3: cannot find package "gotest.tools/v3" in any of:
        c:\go\src\gotest.tools\v3 (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\abc\go\src\gotest.tools\v3 (from $GOPATH)

Comment: OK - looks like you are not using a modules. I would strongly suggest that you consider using them (see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules - running ```go mod init github.com/user/stringutil``` inside the project folder will enable this). If you don't want to use modules then I can take another look (but I use modules for all of my projects now).

Comment: I am not using module. Without using module is it possible?

Comment: You can but need to go back to an older version. I have added extra details to my answer.

Comment: IT worked for me. Used "gotest.tools/v3/assert". Then did - go mod init github.com/user/stringutil and go get gotest.tools/v3.